# how to check the given date is between fromDate and toDate in javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, date, cordova

I am trying to use this below syntex but its not working. plz help

```
var acccID = "acc";
    var date = (new Date().getMonth()+1)+"/"+new Date().getDate()+"/"+new Date().getFullYear();
    var dt1 = (new Date().getMonth()+1)+"/1/"+new Date().getFullYear();
    var dt2 = (new Date().getMonth()+1)+"/31/"+new Date().getFullYear();
    var cr = 5000;

$.mobile.eazydb.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Ledger (Ledger_Account_ID, Ledger_Date, Ledger_Credit, Ledger_Memo)\
                    VALUES("'+acccID+'", "'+date+'", "'+cr+'", "Opening Balanace : Manish")', [],
                function(tx) { alert('ledger entry successfull.');  }, function(err) {   alert('error in inserted : '+err);  
            });
        });

$.mobile.eazydb.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Ledger WHERE Ledger_Date BETWEEN "'+dt1+'" AND "'+dt2+'" ORDER BY Ledger_Date DESC, Ledger_Credit', [],
                function(tx, rs){
                    if(rs.rows.length == 0) {
                        alert('No entries found');
                    } else {
                        for(var i = 0; i<rs.rows.length; i++) {
                            var row = rs.rows.item(i);
                            alert('A/C id : '+row['Ledger_Account_ID']+'\n'+
                                  'Ledger Date : '+row['Ledger_Date']+'\n'+
                                  'Ledger Credit : '+row['Ledger_Credit']+'\n'+
                                  'Ledger Memo : '+row['Ledger_Memo']);
                        }
                    }
            });
        });
```

it only alerts `No entries found`

Comment: Do you need the SQL Query to select date range? Or JS code to check the date range?

Comment: yes i need SQL Query to select the data range

Comment: Can you check whether my answer is useful to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is here in this query `SELECT * FROM Ledger WHERE Ledger_Date BETWEEN "'+dt1+'" AND "'+dt2+'" ORDER BY Ledger_Date DESC, Ledger_Credit`. 
If you want to select the date range in SQL, the date must be in yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy/mm/dd format. So check you dt1 and dt2 variables are in the format mentioned, Print the above select query and inspect the date range arguments. For example your query may look like

```
SELECT * FROM Ledger WHERE Ledger_Date BETWEEN "2013-10-01" AND "2014-11-01" ORDER BY Ledger_Date DESC
```

Comment: I checked it but it didn't work. there is no effect on the output.

Comment: does ur select query look like my example?

Comment: Manish: Check whether your table contains enough data come under the date range!!! Here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c2e5/2

Comment: when i gave insert into Ledger values(1, '2013/7/8'); and for select using   SELECT * FROM Ledger WHERE Ledger_Date BETWEEN "2013/7/1" AND "2013/7/31" ORDER BY Ledger_Date DESC then its not working in my app but its working in sqlfiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b23a9/1 but when i gave the select query as  SELECT * FROM Ledger WHERE Ledger_Date BETWEEN "2013/7/1" AND "2014/7/31" ORDER BY Ledger_Date DESC in code then it also works in my app. what's wrong..???

Comment: did u find the solution? and what it is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal operators:

```
if(currentDate > minDate  && currentDate < maxDate){
// Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution to your problem, but something worth being aware of.  Your date strings are statically defined, making them incompatible with any other locales.  Use ISO date formats in your query instead, since the DB will most likely support them and it allows for localisation:

```
var acccID = "acc",
    now = new Date(),
    dstrNow = now.toISOString(),
    cr = 5000,
    dtStart, dtEnd,
    dstrStart, dstrEnd;

dtStart = new Date();
dtStart.setDate(1);
dstrStart = dtStart.toISOString();

dtEnd = new Date();
dtEnd.setMonth(dtEnd.getMonth() + 1);
dtEnd.setDate(-1);
dstrEnd = dtEnd.toISOString();
```

Substitute your dt1 and dt2 values accordingly, with dstrStart and dstrEnd.